# How can we pass images to the REST service?

Tags: 8

We have a content type with 3 field, title, body and  image field, client side in cross platform mobile application (e.g. Angular or jQuery). We want the mobile users to be able to create a node with the RESTful service.

I read [POST for creating content entities](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rest/post) and [JavaScript and Drupal 8 RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rest/javascript), [Services Quick Start Up Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2424977) and all the examples I saw are about simple text fields.

How can we pass images to the REST service?

Let's suppose our field machine names are title, body, and image.

Comment: This major bug report **[File entities and file/image fields do not currently work with the new REST GET/POST/PATCH/PUT operations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1927648)** makes me believe that you can't at the moment.

Comment: @NoSssweat so you think is better I downgrade to Drupal 7 ?

Comment: I've been following that thread for like 3 weeks now, thought it would be fixed quickly, but doesn't appear to be the case. Seems like they are still figuring out what is the best way to fix it. If your project is time sensitive and you must have the RESTful service with images, then using Drupal 7 is the way to go, for now.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks for you attention, So would you please provide a answer base on Drupal 7 service Module, I don't know how can I pass a image(or file) to REST Drupal service .

Comment: I've never used [webservices](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) (REST) in Drupal 7, so idk exactly how images work. I only started using REST with Drupal 8.